# Tasks submitted to Fixed threadpool ExecutorService are threadsafe?

Tags: java, multithreading, spring

The tasks submitted uses resource beans from a spring container. Are the methods in the beans thread safe when accessed by concurrent threads of a executor service?

Comment: Do you mean that multiple tasks could reference the same resource bean? In that case, it depends on whether the beans are threadsafe themselves, not on how they are used.

Comment: You tell us, they're your beans.  How would we know?

Answer (score 1):

They aren't thread-safe by definition. If your Spring beans are immutable, stateless or properly synchronized (99% of the cases) they are thread safe. Here are few examples of thread-safe Spring beans:

#### Only `final` fields:

```
public class ImmutableService {

    private final Dependency dep;

    @Autowired
    public StatelessService(Dependency dep) {
        this.dep = dep;
    }

    public Foo foo() {
        return dep.foo();
    }

}
```

#### Field is modified only during creation, effectively final:

```
public class EffectivelyImmutableService {

    @Autowired
    private final Dependency dep;

    public Foo foo() {
        return dep.foo();
    }

}
```

#### No state, typical utility class:

```
public class StatelessService {

    public Foo foo() {
        return new Foo();
    }

}
```

#### Non-atomic operations are `synchronized`:

```
public class SynchronizedService {

    private int counter;

    public synchronized Foo foo() {
        return new Foo(counter++);
    }

}
```

#### `AtomicInteger` to avoid explicit synchronization (field is `final`, but the object isn't):

```
public class AtomicService {

    private final AtomicInteger counter = new AtomicInteger();

    public Foo foo() {
        return new Foo(counter.incrementAndGet());
    }

}
```

Note that this rule applies to all use-cases, not only to tasks using Spring beans in thread pool. For instance if your servlets/controllers use Spring beans, they have to be thread safe as well.

Answer (score 0):

If you were to manually start two threads accessing these beans, would the access be threadsafe then? An executor service does no magic and does not change anything about the code running in its threads. If accessing the beans is not threadsafe from two manually started threads, it's not threadsafe when the code is executed by threads managed by an Executor either.